# View Controller contents behind my UIAlertController are being read by VoiceOver

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, accessibility, uialertcontroller, voiceover

I have a `UIAlertController` that I am presenting with a view controller. Before presenting the `UIAlertController` I set `accessibilityViewIsModal` to `true` but when using VoiceOver it still focuses on, and reads out everything on the view controller "behind" the `UIAlertController` (the one that I presented my `UIAlertController` with)

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.accessibilityViewIsModal = true
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any ideas on how I can prevent VoiceOver from reading the content not in the alert dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this after speaking with a colleague.

Setting `accessibilityViewIsModal` on the `view` of the `UIAlertController` fixes this as the view controller itself was not the view VoiceOver was focusing on.

```
alertController.view.accessibilityViewIsModal = true
```

This should be handled automatically though, and therefore I am filing a radar with Apple on it. Will update this answer with the bug ID soon.

Radar filed https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=33779950

Comment: For me this seemed to work only if I set alertController.accessibilityViewIsModal (leaving out the .view part).